# How inkoke a different contract's method in peer cli

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In Hyperledger Fabric I have loaded two contracts in the same chaincode (two controllers). On peer CLI I have manage to call just the first contract method I load in my code.

"Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [Error: You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist: createPost]. Sending ERROR message back to peer"

My index.ts (typescript):
export const contracts: any[] = [stController, PostController];

```
2019-03-25T21:11:23.217Z INFO [contracts-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js] Metadata is : 
 { contracts: 
   { stController: 
      { name: 'stController',
        contractInstance: { name: 'stController', default: true },
        transactions: 
         [ { name: 'initLedger' },
           { name: 'queryStDoc' },
           { name: 'createStDoc' },
           { name: 'queryAllStDocs' },
           { name: 'queryStByOwner' },
           { name: 'changeStOwner' },
           { name: 'cancel' } ],
        info: { title: '', version: '' } },
     PostController: 
      { name: 'PostController',
        contractInstance: { name: 'PostController' },
        transactions: [ { name: 'createPost' }, { name: 'deletePost' } ],
        info: { title: '', version: '' } },
     'org.hyperledger.fabric': 
      { name: 'org.hyperledger.fabric',
        contractInstance: { name: 'org.hyperledger.fabric' },
        transactions: [ { name: 'GetMetadata' } ],
        info: { title: '', version: '' } } },
  info: { version: '1.0.0', title: 'sget' },
  components: { schemas: {} } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this in Typescript, but I have done the same thing in JavaScript - I used a supertype in both contracts to get a namespace to differentiate between the contracts. (In my example I had duplicate function names - 2 copies of Fabcar.)

```
    constructor() {
    super('org.example.car');
    }


    constructor() {
    super('org.example.rob');
    }
```

I then invoked the functions from the cli as follows:

`peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["org.example.car:queryCar","CAR2"]}' -n fcnstest`

and

`peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["org.example.rob:changeCarOwner","CAR2","Rob"]}' -n fcnstest`

The [Commercial Paper tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/commercial_paper.html) has an example of using a namespace/supertype.  But it is also Javascript not typescript.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just replace the namespace you had created in the constructor by the class's name in the invoke and it works!!! Example: peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["PostController:CreatePost","IDx", ...etc]}' -n <chaincodename>